# jasmine setup error rails 3.1 ActiveSupport::Concern (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec-rails, jasmine

I am trying to setup the Jasmine Gem as described on their website. After running:

```
bundle exec jasmine init
```

I get an error:

```
/Users/sts-158imac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@fmn/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:4:in `<module:Configurable>': uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Concern (NameError)
from /Users/sts-158imac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@fmn/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:3:in `<class:Railtie>'
from /Users/sts-158imac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@fmn/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:2:in `<module:Rails>'
from /Users/sts-158imac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@fmn/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/sts-158imac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@fmn/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:129:in `inherited'
from /Users/sts-158imac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@fmn/gems/jasmine-1.0.2.1/lib/jasmine/railtie.rb:3:in `<module:Jasmine>'
from /Users/sts-158imac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@fmn/gems/jasmine-1.0.2.1/lib/jasmine/railtie.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/sts-158imac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@fmn/gems/jasmine-1.0.2.1/lib/jasmine.rb:12:in `require'
from /Users/sts-158imac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@fmn/gems/jasmine-1.0.2.1/lib/jasmine.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/sts-158imac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@fmn/gems/jasmine-1.0.2.1/bin/jasmine:4:in `require'
from /Users/sts-158imac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@fmn/gems/jasmine-1.0.2.1/bin/jasmine:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/sts-158imac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@fmn/bin/jasmine:19:in `load'
from /Users/sts-158imac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@fmn/bin/jasmine:19:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of trying to setup Jamine with `bundle exec jasmine init`

try using `rails g jasmine:install`  which will be available once you bundle install after inserting jasmine gem in your Gemfile.
`